# Let $G$ be generated by $\begin{pmatrix}1&p\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ p&1\end{pmatrix}$ for prime $p$. Is $G$ is solvable? A proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, solvable-groups

Here is a problem determining the solvability of the given group.

> Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ generated by two elements
> $$
> \begin{pmatrix}1 & p \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ p & 1 \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> where $p$ is a prime integer. Determine whether $G$ is solvable or not.

By letting $A$ the former matrix, the latter is $A^t$.
I guess that $G$ is not solvable as it is isomorphic to the free group $F_2$ with two generators.
This is because there is no nontrivial relation that $A$ and $A^t$ satisfies: that is, $A^m \neq I$, $(A^t)^n \neq I$ for every nonzero integer $m$ and $n$, and their arbitrary product cannot also form an identity matrix (I think.)
However, as $A_5$ is generated by two elements, namely a $5$-cycle and a product of two disjoint transpositions, $F_2$ cannot be solvable as $A_5$ is a factor group of $F_2$, which is not solvable.
Hence $G$ is also not solvable.

My question is, is my guess correct?
Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  Are you asking for a proof or disproof of "their arbitrary product cannot also form an identity matrix (I think.)"?  That's where the "guess" is, certainly.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, that will be the main point of my question. Are there any ways to show it (or disprove) without brutal force? I think direct calculation might not be sufficient to show (if it is true).

Comment: My guess is that $G=\{A\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z):A\equiv I_2\pmod p\}$.

Comment: You now have two possible proofs, the one you outline and the one proposed by spin. I am not sure which one would be shorter if you wrote out all of the details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any prime $r$, the group $SL_2(r)$ is generated by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Thus $G$ has $SL_2(r)$ as a quotient for any prime $r \neq p$, and so $G$ is not solvable.

Comment: $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has a free subgroup of rank $2$ (Sanov group). So any subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of finite index is not solvable. If $G = \{A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) : A = I_2 \mod p\}$ then $G$ is of finite index in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and hence not solvable. Is this the proof you are trying to give ? If so, how would you prove that $G = \{A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) : A = I_2 \mod p\}$ ?

Comment: No, I am just answering the question of whether $G$ is solvable. There is a homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z})$. The image of $G$ under this homomorphism is $SL_2(r)$.

Comment: Thanks. Can u pls define $SL_2(r)$ ? The generators you have given are generators of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: For a prime $r$, we denote $SL_2(r) = SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z})$. The generators in the answer are the images of the generators of $G$ in $SL_2(r)$, by abuse of notation

Comment: Thanks, So the proof is over if $SL_2(r)$ for some $r \neq p$ is not solvable. Got it. Thanks

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Or $r = 3$.

Answer (score 4):

Denote
$$
x=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & p\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\
y=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
p & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since we only need to prove that the group $G=\langle x,y\rangle$ is not solvable, we can reason this way.

If $G$ is solvable, then it has a nontrivial normal abelian subgroup $A$
(for example, the last nontrivial member  of the derived series of $G$).
Let
$$
v=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\in A,\ v\neq I.
$$
We have
$$
z=x^{-1}vx=
\begin{pmatrix}
a-pc & *\\
c & d+pc
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We don't need an entry at position $(1,2)$ and I didn't calculate it.
Since $v,z\in A$ and $A$ is abelian, it follows that matrices $v$ and $z$ commute.
The entry of the matrix $zv$ at position $(2,1)$ is $ac+cd+pc^2$.
At the same position in the matrix $vz$ there is $ac+cd-pc^2$.
Hence $c=0$.

I think the rest is clear, because we still have matrix $y$ in reserve.

Comment: Can u explain why $G$ if solvable contain a non-trivial normal abelian subgroup ? I agree that $G$ if solvable contain a non-trivial abelian group which is normal w.r.t another subgroup $G_2$ but $G_2$ need not be same as $G$ ?

Comment: Its a sub-normal series and not a normal series, I think. So $G^{(s-1)}$ is normal in $G^{(s-2)}$ and need not be normal in $G$ ?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Derived_series) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_series#Normal_series.2C_subnormal_series),
better yet, prove on your own that every member of the derived series is normal in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Got it. Cheers !

Comment: Always happy to help.